# Find tables where PK is the same as the FK

Tags: database-design, information-schema

How can i find all the tables in a database where the PK is the same as the FK using the information schema? I need this to generate a script that converts a database into a data vault. By determining if a table is a link i need too know if the table has a fk that is the same as the pk.

I'm using ms sql and the default information schema that are available in the database.

Comment: Wich RDBMS? What "information schema"? And why should the PK equal the FK? Do you want a list of all tables that have a FK to a given source table?

Comment: there's two ways that this can be interpreted: 1- you're looking for all tables where the primary key is being used as a foreign key in antoher table, 2- you're lookg for all tables that self-reference their primary key in the table.  which one are you wanting?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS;
```

Comment: YEAH but how to get a list of tables where the PK is the same as the FK

Answer (score 0):

There is an information schema, which allows to query table definitions using pre-defined views.

Comment: YEAH but how to get a list of tables where the PK is the same as the FK

Comment: @Bas: you read the docs and go "oh wow, there's the table_constraints view!"